# How do I get values from this Formik reactjs Input?

Tags: reactjs, formik

I am building a recipe database and I want to make it so that users can add and remove steps in an instructions. When a user clicks the "add step" button, it would add a new input.

```
 <h4>Instructions</h4>
              {Array.from(Array(step)).map((c, index) => {
                const stepNumber = index + 1;
                return (
                  <Field
                    type="text"
                    name={`instructions[${index}]`}
                    placeholder={`Instructions step ${stepNumber}`}
                    component={Input}
                    onChange={e => setIngredients(e.target.value)}
                  />
                );
              })}
              <ButtonWrapper>
                <Button
                  recipe
                  type="button"
                  onClick={() => handleInstructionRemove()}
                  contain
                >
                  Remove Last Instruction
                </Button>
                <Button
                  color="green"
                  contain
                  type="button"
                  onClick={() => setStep(step + 1)}
                >
                  Add Step
                </Button>
              </ButtonWrapper>
```

I am using useState to get the number of steps

```
  const [step, setStep] = useState(1);
```

I can successfully add, remove, and type in the inputs without creating any issues, but when I go to submit it none of the information is captured. I am using Formik to create the form.

```
 <Formik
      initialValues={{
        title: "",
        author: "",
        ingredients: [],
        amount: [],
        size: [],
        temperature: "",
        degrees: "f",
        instructions: [],
        cookingTime: "",
        description: "",
        serving: "",
        category: "main",
        image: null
      }}
      validationSchema={RecipeSchema}
      onSubmit={async (values) => {
        try {
          const url = await handleUpload();
          createRecipe(values, url);
          // history.push('/');
          console.log(values);

        } catch (err) {
          console.log(err);
        }
      }}
    >
```

The component itself is very long so sorry that I broke it into chunks. There are a lot of fields in it so I hope I gave enough. Any advice is much appreciated!

Comment: My initial thought is that something is going wrong either in the  `await handleUpload()` or `createRecipe(values,url)`. Can you remove those and just `console.log(values)` to see if the values are pulling through

Comment: Yeah so thats what I have been doing, i accidentally just uncommented it again. The values are listed just as an empty array. I'm guessing there is an issue with how I set it up but I'm not sure the right way to pull them into an array

Comment: The best way going forward is to create a minimal reproducible example on codesandbox so that we can actually try it out and attempt to help solve the problem

Comment: Oh I will do that tomorrow! Have to log off for the night but I appreciate the responses!

Comment: I haven't been able to figure out how to make it in a codesandbox, but I did realize that if I remove the   onChange={e => setIngredients(e.target.value)}, it fixes the issue. But then it creates the issue of an uncontrolled input. So I'm not sure how to make it a controlled input with how it is set up

Comment: Would this work? Using the formik hook : https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-albattani-1twp5e?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Thank you for both teaching me how to set up a codesandbox and for figuring out that error! I tried applying that same setup to 2 other inputs that were having that issue and I don't understand why it doesn't work for them. Those 2 inputs are part of a different map with a similar setup. The only difference is this is tracking the amount and ingredient name.

Comment: I added it to the codesandbox

Comment: When I looked back, it looks like even the codesandbox still has the error so I'm not sure what the move is

Comment: When you edit a codesandbox, it's going to fork the project to your account. So any changes you make, you'll need to send me a link to 'your one'

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-galileo-zpzyvd?file=/src/App.js

All 3 inputs give the error

Comment: Was easier to use an array of objects to hold the instruction / ingredient and amount. Up to you how you'd want to go about it but that seemed to have simplified things https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-violet-e3ecxw?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Sorry it took me so long to respond, got busy with life but thank you so much for your help! The solution you posted solved my issue!